# How to set the padding and placement if we have more than 16 data in the series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So i have 20 data in series and i dont know how to calculate the placement and padding and make it works. Here is the jsFiddle link

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5znwjwek/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        },{
            name: 'Employees1',
            color: 'rgba(125,110,217,1)',
            data: [140, 43, 70],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized1',
            color: 'rgba(126,186,134,.9)',
            data: [130, 40, 10],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit1',
            color: 'rgba(148,161,163,1)',
            data: [83.6, 148.8, 98.5],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized1',
            color: 'rgba(186,50,67,.9)',
            data: [213.6, 148.8, 208.5],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        },{
            name: 'Employees2',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,117,1)',
            data: [170, 33, 30],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized2',
            color: 'rgba(146,86,114,.9)',
            data: [120, 30, 60],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit2',
            color: 'rgba(248,121,61,1)',
            data: [123.6, 278.8, 128.5],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized2',
            color: 'rgba(126,40,21,.9)',
            data: [213.6, 298.8, 198.5],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        },{
            name: 'Employees3',
            color: 'rgba(164,120,117,1)',
            data: [120, 93, 30],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized3',
            color: 'rgba(116,86,114,.9)',
            data: [150, 80, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit3',
            color: 'rgba(148,191,163,1)',
            data: [143.6, 158.8, 298.5],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized3',
            color: 'rgba(146,160,161,.9)',
            data: [243.6, 118.8, 218.5],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        },{
            name: 'Employees4',
            color: 'rgba(185,120,207,1)',
            data: [190, 173, 120],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized4',
            color: 'rgba(156,186,124,.9)',
            data: [110, 45, 183],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit4',
            color: 'rgba(218,161,163,1)',
            data: [143.6, 218.8, 238.5],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized4',
            color: 'rgba(126,60,51,.9)',
            data: [253.6, 118.8, 258.5],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the working fiddle

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/5znwjwek/1/'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this code it may help you.

To reduce the width of bar you have to increase the value of **pointPadding** and for maintaining distance between bars use **pointPlacement**.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.1
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.12
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.14
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.16
        },{
            name: 'Employees1',
            color: 'rgba(125,110,217,1)',
            data: [140, 43, 70],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.18
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized1',
            color: 'rgba(126,186,134,.9)',
            data: [130, 40, 10],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit1',
            color: 'rgba(148,161,163,1)',
            data: [83.6, 148.8, 98.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.22
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized1',
            color: 'rgba(186,50,67,.9)',
            data: [213.6, 148.8, 208.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.24
        },{
            name: 'Employees2',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,117,1)',
            data: [170, 33, 30],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.26
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized2',
            color: 'rgba(146,86,114,.9)',
            data: [120, 30, 60],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.28
        }, {
            name: 'Profit2',
            color: 'rgba(248,121,61,1)',
            data: [123.6, 278.8, 128.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.30
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized2',
            color: 'rgba(126,40,21,.9)',
            data: [213.6, 298.8, 198.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.32
        },{
            name: 'Employees3',
            color: 'rgba(164,120,117,1)',
            data: [120, 93, 30],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.34
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized3',
            color: 'rgba(116,86,114,.9)',
            data: [150, 80, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.36
        }, {
            name: 'Profit3',
            color: 'rgba(148,191,163,1)',
            data: [143.6, 158.8, 298.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.38
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized3',
            color: 'rgba(146,160,161,.9)',
            data: [243.6, 118.8, 218.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.40
        },{
            name: 'Employees4',
            color: 'rgba(185,120,207,1)',
            data: [190, 173, 120],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.42
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized4',
            color: 'rgba(156,186,124,.9)',
            data: [110, 45, 183],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.44
        }, {
            name: 'Profit4',
            color: 'rgba(218,161,163,1)',
            data: [143.6, 218.8, 238.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.46
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized4',
            color: 'rgba(126,60,51,.9)',
            data: [253.6, 118.8, 258.5],
            pointPadding: 0.5,
            pointPlacement: -0.48
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: its not helping. If you have idea, please edit the code in JSfiddle and show it. Thanks for your response

Comment: Thanks for your work. But i behave as a Column chart. I want fixed column chart

Comment: what do you mean by fixed column chart here ?? I didnt get you .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-placement/ . This is fixed column chart

Comment: The above one is also fixed column . only i changed the value of pointPadding and pointPlacement so that all the bars will be visible properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79319/discussion-between-thinker-and-shreya).